# How to multiply two float variables in masm

Tags: x86, masm

How to multiply two float variables in masm, assembly user enters an input as 3.02 and multiply it with 0.008 and then print it

```
.data 
fin dd 5.0

.code
main proc

fld fin
fmul fin  ;to multiply fin with fin 
fstp dword [eax]   ;cannot mov result in eax
call writefloat

exit 
main EndP
end main
```

Comment: This code loads `fin` and multiplies it by `fin`. That's the same as fin^2 (squared). Your `fmul` should take as its operand the value you want to multiply `fin` *by*. But the code doesn't match with the question, since `fin` is a constant 5.0, whereas you're talking about multiplying 3.02 x 0.008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the FPU keep in mind that it used a stacked set of registers that can only be loaded from, or saved to, memory.
I assume you can document about the FPU programming model by yourself, either by using the [Intel manual 1](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-1-manual.html) or, if you feel nostalgic, by [reading this 387 manual from Intel dated 05/26/1987](http://www.ragestorm.net/downloads/387intel.txt).

The instruction `fstp dword [eax]` save the content of `st(0)` at *the address denoted* by `eax`. This kind of addressing mode is an *indirect addressing mode* and it is consistently marked with the use of square brackets in the Intel assembly syntax.
Contrast this with saving `st(0)` in `eax`, that should look like `fstp eax` (no brackets).
Alas, the latter is not supported, probably because the FPU supports 64-bit and 80-bit formats that couldn't, at the time, fit any register.

---

To push data. from memory, into the FPU stack use `fld`, to pop the registers, into memory, use `fstp` (or `fst` if you don't want to pop the stack).
To perform a multiplication use `fmul`, it comes in a few variant, one of which can operate with a memory operand and store the result directly in `st(0)`.

If you feel paranoid you can use `finit` at the start of the program, this instruction resets the control registers of the FPU to mark the registers empty.
The OS should start your process with a clean state already.

Here a simple example:

```
.DATA

  A dd 5.0
  B dq 0.008

  C dd 0            ;Move into a BSS section if the assembler support it

.CODE

  finit              ;For paranoid only

  fld DWORD [A]      ;ST(0) = A
  fmul QWORD [B]     ;ST(0) = ST(0)*B = A*B
  fstp DWORD [C]     ;C = ST(0) = A*B

  mov eax, DWORD [C] ;EAX = C = A*B
  call writefloat
```

---

As today you can use the vector registers with scalar instructions.
You can find the relevant documentation still in the Intel manual linked previously.

```
.DATA

  A dd 5.0          ;Use float
  B dd 0.008        ;Use float again, avoid cvtss2sd

  C dd 0            ;Move into a BSS section if the assembler support it

.CODE

 movss xmm0, DWORD PTR [A]    ;xmm0.f[0] = A
 mulss xmm0, DWORD PTR [B]    ;xmm0.f[0] = A * B
 movd eax, xmm0               ;eax = xmm0.f[0] = A * B
                              ;Beware, 1 extra cycle for bypass delay
 call writefloat
```